# Evaluating a strange sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm a first year undergrad maths student and I've come across this particular sequence, which I can't find a limit for.

$$\underbrace{\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\cdots}}}}}_{n \text{ times}}$$

I know this may be embarrassingly easy, but I can't think of a way to start. Can you share any hints?

Comment: Whatever the limit is, it must satisfy $x=(10x)^{1/2}$ (why?) Then simplify this.

Comment: Should you check that a limit exists first?

Comment: One needs to assign meaning to the expression in the OP.  As written, it is ambiguous.  The rigorous way forward requires a recurrence relationship for the sequence and an initial value.  The way that this is written, the initial value is concealed.  Please see my answer and please let me know how I can improve it.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well..:

$$\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\cdots}}}} =  10^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots}$$

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with it. This is merely a sketch or hint, as the OP asked for

Comment: @Dr.MV This is rigorous (or can be made rigorous) if you use the fact that the function $f(x)=10^x$ is continuous and evaluate the infinite sum in the exponent as a limit of partial sums.

Comment: @michaelburr The expression $10^{\sum_n 2^{-n}}$ is well-defined.  The original expression is not.  But if we use the former to define the latter, then I completely agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

We have the recurrence relationship

$$x_{n+1}=\sqrt{10x_n}\implies x_{n+1}^2=10x_n$$

If $x_0=0$, then $x_n=0$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=0$.

If $x_0=10$, then $x_n=10$ for all $n$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=10$.

If $10>x_0>0$, then clearly $0<x_n<x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ is increasing.  And since $x_0<10$, the sequence is clearly bounded above by $10$.  Since $x_n$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above it converges.  Let's call this limit $L$.  Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}=L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{10x_n}=\sqrt{10L}\implies L=10$

If $10<x$, then clearly $x_n>x_{n+1}>0$ and $x_n$ is decreasing.  And since $x_n>0$, the sequence is clearly bounded below by $0$.  Since $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below it converges.  Let's call this limit $L$.  Thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}=L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{10x_n}=\sqrt{10L}\implies L=10$.

Putting it all together, we have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n=
\begin{cases}
10&,x_0>0\\\\
0&,x_0=0
\end{cases}
$$

and we are done!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, all the others only use intuitive nonrigurous approaches.

Comment: That's pretty good.  I had a TA once claim $ x =\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^{...}}= 2 $ because $\sqrt{2}^x = x$ would mean x = 2.  This would put a stop to that right away.

Comment: @yotengunlcd Thank you so much!  That made my weekend.

Comment: @fleablood Thank you.  And yes, I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\cdots}}}$.  Then, $x^2=10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\sqrt{10\cdots}}}=10x$.  Therefore, $x^2=10x$, so $x=10$.

Comment: This is not quite the rigorous way to proceed.  One needs to assign meaning to the expression as written.  The rigorous way forward requires a recurrence that has an initial value.  The way that this is written, the initial value is concealed. If it were $0$, then, clearly the answer would be $0$, not $10$ as this result produces.  But, this is a typical incorrect approach that is seen often.

Comment: Yes, it is not rigorous.  One would need to let $a_0=1$ and $a_n=\sqrt{10a_{n-1}}$ and squeeze the result (as you do in your answer).